# how to rename a column in linux?

Tags: linux, sed, rename

I have a table like this

```
 bedGraph  chrom=chr1 chr1:0-000
    1000    0
    2000    0
    3000    0.003802
    4000    0.046175
 bedGraph  chrom=chr2 chr2:5000-6000
    5000    0.103756
    6000    0.161337

 EXPECTED RESULTS

bedGraph  chrom=chr1 rep
    1000    0
    2000    0
    3000    0.003802
    4000    0.046175
 bedGraph  chrom=chr2 rep
    5000    0.103756
    6000    0.161337
```

and I would like to rename the 3rd col only (the 2nd cols changes along the file). Is possible to do that using `sed`? 
Thanks!

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: I've just posted the expected results as suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/bedGraph/s/chr[12]:.*/rep/'
```

For the lines containing `badGraph` substitute `chr[1 or 2]:<anything>` for `rep`.

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)[^[:space:]]\+$/\1 rep/'
```

Filter and remember first two words in the line with `[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+[^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+` which bassically means: `<spaces or nothing><not spaces><spaces><not spaces><spaces>` then filter out the third word with `[^[:space:]]\+` and print the first two words (ie. the first match) and substitute the third column with rep.

Answer (score 2):

For the given example, this one-liner works:

```
awk 'NF==3{$3="rep"}7' file
```

Comment: That `7` on the end can be any number except zero?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes....